# How to design database to keep list of special members among all members?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I want to design Database which works  as   below explained.

1. We have some members and they are listed in many categories.
2. Among members, some have special privileges.
3. We have Memeber Table
4. We have Category Table
5. Member- category relation maintained in separate table
6. Member- privilege relation maintained in separate table

Now we want to retrieve members for the particular category , this can be achieved by accessing  **Member-category** table but in my case I also want to know there privilege , to achieve one thing I can do is

**Compare The result (query result- member-category) with Member-Privilege Table**  and Check whether Member has privilege or not .

THis is seems to be OK in general case but in this case , We want to make sure Member that have privilege must be included in all result , if "Category" linked to privileged Member .

CASE : 1
When I query for members in category with out limit , I get all the members and then I can compare against Privilege table . This is OK 
Case 2 : when I query for members in category with LIMIT , I may miss some of the members who have privileges due to limit ( like LIMIT 10 .. etc )
in that case I will not get all privileged members

How to design database so that I always get privileged members from database quires against category

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Isn't a single query with a JOIN clause and a LIMIT X clause guaranteed to return X privileged members in the right category?

Comment: As I read this, the problem is that ALL privileged members should be returned, irregardless of the LIMIT.

Comment: Just run two queries

Comment: Which is something you can't force on DB-level, hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't design your database that way, but you can write your queries (or rather, design your application) to handle that. The example with the LIMIT simply cannot be handled on the database because you can't change what LIMIT does fundamentally.

Your example seems weird because a limit bascially means 'give me only X results'. What do you want to do if there are 12 privileged members, 15 'ordinary' members and you LIMIT 10? Return all 12 privileged and no ordinary? Return all priviledged members and 10 ordinary members? This is the kind of decision you have to make in your application and handle everything that way from the application, not the database...

(Failing that, I suppose you could write a stored procedure to handle this and wrap your logic in that. That leaves you with a database-only solution, but still does not prevent anybody from simply querying the data)

Comment: My best guess as to what OP meant is that he's currently doing two queries with LIMIT 10s, so he sometimes gets less than 10 privileged members at the end, but he doesn't realize he can write a single JOIN with LIMIT 10 query that always gets 10 privileged members (if at least 10 exist). Hopefully he'll clarify this someday.

Comment: @Ixrec You are correct , That is what it worrying me. I cant just join two tables , So I decided to keep All category-members in one master table and copy all privileged members-category data to separate table and query both and merge for further process, When Row copied to new table  I making status of that row 0 in master table , so that I can avoid duplicates .. Is this good practice ??

Comment: @SathyamShivamSundaram Is there a specific reason why you "can't just join two tables"? That's a fairly basic operation in most RDBMSs, and avoiding it is unlikely to be a "good practice".

Comment: @Ixrec have 10 bags and 3 of them is privileged , no matter what ever the LIMIT is at any cost I have to pick all 3 privileged bags + normal bags matching query , add them ranking and keep top above normal bags , If my Limit is 2 , as you said I will miss 1 prv bag , its undesired . So I separated prv bag and  put it in separate table , now I query both table for matching bags ( with same parameter)  and merge result .LIMIT applied to normal bag table will not hurt prvlgd bag table.  Is my thinking bad practice ??

Comment: @SathyamShivamSundaram Still sounds like something you can do in one query to me. If I understand you correctly, the "right" way of doing that is to have the privilege level of each bag stored in a table somewhere, so that when you JOIN all the relevant tables you can do an ORDER BY on the privilege level, and *then* LIMIT the result. (if you need further help this may be worth asking a new question)

Comment: So what do you want your application to do if you have 3 privileged bags, some normal bags and LIMIT is 2? What should that return?